# Postman: How to check the data type of each value in a response

Tags: javascript, postman

How do I check that the data type of each value in an API response is NOT an integer?

For example, if my API returns this:

```
 "teamPermissions": [
    "Edit",
    "Administrator",
    "ReadOnly",
    etc
    ]
```

I need a Postman test to make sure that an integer is never returned in the `teamPermission` array.

Here's what I started but need assistance:

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
tests["Team Permissions Do Not Contain Integers"] = typeof(jsonData.teamPermissions) !== "number"
```

This passes because `teamPermissions` is an object but how do I check each value of the object is not an integer?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This should do the check for you:

```
pm.test('Not contain numbers', () => {
    var jsonData = pm.response.json()
    for (i = 0; i < jsonData.teamPermissions.length; i++) {
        pm.expect(jsonData.teamPermissions[i]).to.not.be.a('number')
    }
})
```

Here's what the check will do if a number is part of the array, I've logged out the types so you can see what it's checking against.

[image: Postman]

Another alternative is to use [Lodash](https://lodash.com/), it's a build-in module for the Postman native app. This code will run the same check as the one above:

```
pm.test('Not contain numbers', () => {
    _.each(pm.response.json().teamPermissions, (arrItem) => {
        pm.expect(arrItem).to.not.be.a('number')
    })
})
```

Comment: Doesn't this output whatever you type in the quotes? I.e., replace 'number' with 'blah'. I just get, "to not be a blah". Is it supposed to do that?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `teamPermissions` is an Array.

You could use [`Array.prototype.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) to check if all the elements pass some condition:

```
var array1 = [1, 2, 3];
var array2 = ["a", 9, 10];
console.log(array1.every((e) => { return !isNaN(e) })) // True, all elements are numbers
console.log(array2.every((e) => { return !isNaN(e) })) // False
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you can do something like this:

```
jsonData.forEach((a)=>{
var boolVal=isNaN(a) ? true : false
if(boolVal)
{
    tests["Team Permissions Do Not Contain Integers"]=false; 
 }
});
```

FYI , Instead isNaN(a) you can also do Number.isInteger(a)

Comment: Why don't you just put your check inside the test? `jsonData.forEach( value => tests['Team Permissions Contain Integers''] = Number.isInteger(value));`. Due to coercion you don't need to use ternary operator and if block.